# Change Language in JavaScript and php file

Tags: javascript, php

I build website with two language and I have script API from company 
and this script is search box it has multi-languages now to change language box just add to url: `?language=ar`. example `www.site.com/index.php?language=ar`.
When change language website by session I put also redirect to `index.php?language=ar` 
like this:

```
<?php
function make_lang(){

    if ($_POST['ar']){
        $_COOKIE['ar']=true;
        unset($_COOKIE['en']);
    }
    if ($_POST['en']){
        $_COOKIE['en']=true;
        unset($_COOKIE['ar']);
    }
}

function make_plang(){

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['en'])){
        isset($_COOKIE['ar']);
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['ar'])){
        $lang = "ar";
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['en'])){
        $lang = "en";
    }

    $path = dirname(__FILE__)."/lang/".$lang.".php";
    return $path;
}

function lang_js(){
    if (isset($_COOKIE['ar'])){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "index.php?language=ar"
        </script>';
    }
    if (isset($_COOKIE['en'])){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "index.php?language=en"
        </script>';
    }
}

make_lang();
$langFile = make_plang();
include($langFile);
lang_js();
?>
```

But just change language for script. How can change two thing page and script?

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the language with $_GET['language'], because from your description I see that the lang request comes from the request, but you are searching from the POST and with wrong key.

Comment: i use this also before and same problem